# Can I use comma after "because" in the middle of the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is the following comma after "because" correct or not?

> I don't like flowers **because,** they smell bad.

If not, why?

---

For reference, my full sentence:

> An effective leader is who connects skills and personalities which are shaped by experience, and not always realistic to leadership expectations without sex difference **because,** accomplishment oriented development efforts in American culture and are often effective whether qualities of traits are masculine or feminine as long as has empathetic influence towards tasks.

Comment: Unless for some reason your putting a parenthetical element after 'because', a comma should never come after it.

Comment: Umm... unless your using it as a noun as I did in the previous comment.  lol

Comment: Welcome to SE! What research have you done regarding commas and _because_?

Comment: Strangely, I could find no stated rule that a comma should not come after *because*. I simply know that it shouldn't. (Unless, as per the first comment here, what comes after is a subordinate clause.) There could be a series of grammar rules that, in combination, result in such a conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't, but you can say this instead:

> I don't like flowers, because they smell bad.

Anyway it doesn't sound natural, but it's correct. It's better if you say

> I don't like flowers because they smell bad.

Comment: thanks, btw i'm trying to find a written rule? How do you exactly give this answer, "better" according to whom?

Comment: The two examples you provided have completely different meanings.

Comment: The first sentence: *Flowers smell bad and that's why I don't like them.* The second sentence: *It's not due to them smelling bad that I like flowers (there is some other reason I like them).*